# Get the id of the first div element inside a container div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've cut down my page to just the relevant content. See code here:

```js
let text = document.getElementById("apanelofcontent").firstChild.id;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="apanelofcontent" id="apanelofcontent">
  <div class="panel1" id="panel1" name="panel1">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel1link" id="panel1link">
    <p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open modal</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I want to do is get the `id` value from the first `div` to appear within the `div` with the `apanelofcontent` as `id`.

So in the above example I want the console to display the text `panel1` as that’s the `id` of the first `div` to appear within the `div` with `apanelofcontent` as `id`.

If I run the above, all I get in the alert window is `undefined`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) could be just a text node, that space before the `div`, which doesn't have an `id`. You could use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild), which gets you the first element node, like so:

```html
<html>
  <div class="apanelofcontent" id="apanelofcontent">
    <div class="panel1" id="panel1" name="panel1">
      <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel1link" id="panel1link">
        <p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open modal</a></p>
    </div>
      <script>
        let text = document.getElementById("apanelofcontent").firstElementChild.id;
        window.alert(text);
      </script>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints `panel1` to console:

```js
let firstDivChildId = document.querySelector('div#apanelofcontent > div:first-of-type').id;
//window.alert(firstDivChildId );
console.log(firstDivChildId  )
```

```html
<div class="apanelofcontent" id="apanelofcontent">
  <div class="panel1" id="panel1" name="panel1">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel1link" id="panel1link">
    <p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open modal</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```